# How do you round() a map function in python?

Tags: python, mapping, rounding

I am trying to do this,

```
  print(list(round(map(radius, cirumfrence), 1)))
```

but it comes up with this error:/

```
    print(list(round(map(radius, cirumfrence), 1)))
TypeError: type map doesn't define __round__ method
```

Anyone know what the problem is?
Thanks!

Here is the whole code.

```
  cirumfrence = [2.7, 69, 7, 2]

  radius = lambda circ: ((circ)/2*math.pi)

  print(list(map(round(radius, cirumfrence))))
```

Comment: Did you mean to round each individual result that `map` produces? You're calling `round` on the whole result set right now, which won't work.

Comment: Yes! How should I go about doing that?

Comment: You could use another call to `map` or with a `lambda`, but at this point, it might be more readable to just use a list comprehension.

Comment: Alternatively,  why don't you simply return the rounded value from `radius`?

Comment: I provided more code so maybe you could help me out. I am trying to learn mapping and lambda right now so if you could maybe provide a little code to help me out that would be amazing!

Comment: _Anyone know what the problem is?_ You're using `round()` on the `map` object. As an aside, don't assign a lambda to a name, just define a proper function. Also, if you're using `list(map())`, you might as well just use a list comprehension.

Comment: Again, why not simply return the rounded value from the function? `round(((circ)/2*math.pi), 1)`

Comment: @AMC in some cases `list(map(...))` will have better performance (runtime-wise) than the equivalent list comp

Comment: @DeepSpace Is the difference substantial?

Comment: @AMC In some cases more than others

Comment: @AMC Technically I could also just do this. radius = [round(((circumfrence[i])/2*math.pi), 1) for i in range(len(circumfrence))]

Comment: @ChristopherSaia `[round(circum / 2 * math.pi, 1) for circum in circumference]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
cirumfrence = [2.7, 69, 7, 2]

radius = lambda circ: ((circ)/2*math.pi)

new_lst = [round(radius(x),2) for x in cirumfrence]
```

Output:
[4.24, 108.38, 11.0, 3.14]